# Magento 2 : Customer import not working and gives "Import successfully done"

Tags: magento2, customer, import, importexport

I have around 1000 customer to import when I try customer import using magento2 default customer import. Validation works perfectly and when I start import it gives me the message "Import successfully done" but no customer imported.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have reindexed all the indexes or your customer grid would not show imported customers. Use following command.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**EDIT :**

Note that if you're only not able to see the customers in admin you can also run;

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

this will only reindex the indices corresponding to customer grid and populate data in the corresponding flat table.

Answer (score 0):

Reindex all indexes. After that all your customers will be listed.

Answer (score 0):

just go to your Magento root directory by using command line prompt and type

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex` this command

it will definitely show you the latest imported record of customers in admin